# I'd like to create a Table and got an error message 'unexpected token'. How can I correct this?

Tags: r

`table1(~ 0 days + 1 - 13 days + 14+ days + Don't know/Refused/missing | status, data = ne2, overall = "Total")`

Comment: What is `Don't know/Refused/missing`? Is that a single column, or are you trying to do some OR-logic aggregation? If it's an actual column name, then enclose it in backticks, as in `\`Don't know/Refused/missing\``.

Comment: Otherwise, it'll be very difficult to help without knowing anything about `ne2`. Can you please [edit] your question and include the output from `dput(head(ne2))`?

Comment: “0 days”, “1-13 days”, “14+ days”, and “Don’t know/Refused/Missing are value labels; with values assigned 1, 2, 3, 9 respectively.  The variable (column) is titled 'ment14d'.  The goal is to convert the variable to factor variables.

Comment: > dput(head(ne2))
structure(list(state = c(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9), sleptim1 = c(8, 20, 
10, 10, 7, 8), sex1 = c(7, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2), ment14d = c(1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1), bmi5 = c(2661, 2834, 2792, 2880, 2554, 3203)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))